# How to update Some Fields dynamically inside a div

Tags: jquery

When clicked on **Next** and **Prev** Buttons i need to Update the Count of Navigation  inside the div .

(For Example : **Showing 2 Of 10 Items** )

And When clicked on Next Button again this should be

**( Showing 3 Of 10 Items )**

This is my html and the js logic

Could any body please let me know how to update div fields dynamically

```
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
<input type="button" id="prev" value="Prev">
<div id="countdiv">
     <Span>Showing  </Span> Of <span>Items</span>

</div>



var totalcount = 10;
var current_count = 0;



$(document).on('click', '#prev', function (event) {
    if (current_count > 1) {
        current_count--;
        updateDiv();
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#next', function (event) {
    if (current_count < totalcount) {
        current_count++;
        updateDiv();
    }
});

function updateDiv() {


}
```

THis is my fiddle , could anybody please help me

http://jsfiddle.net/6xskkzjh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function updateDiv() {
        $('#countdiv').html('Showing '+current_count+' of'+totalcount+' items');            
}
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6xskkzjh/4/)

Comment: @Aditya Pass current_count and total_count as parameters to updateDiv() instead of making those variables global.

Comment: @Hoa yes you are right that's a good idea. But I have just modified the original code posted by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You have add two more element.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xskkzjh/7/

```
function updateDiv() {
    $('#val').html(current_count);
    $('#total').html(totalcount);

}

 <div id="countdiv">
     <Span>Showing</Span><Span id='val'></Span> Of <span id='total'></span> <span>Items</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 function updateDiv() {
        $('#countdiv').html('Showing '+current_count+' of'+totalcount+' items');

    }
```

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6xskkzjh/6/)